# is it possible to achieve path based routing behind aws NLB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

**I have a use case:-** where my I have a lot of traffic coming to my webservers so I need greater performs and better latency however there are 2 paths to which traffic is incoming.

**as per my understanding this is achievable with aws NLB which scales to 1000's request per second and 100 ms sub latency**.

however I have `www.jatin.com` and `www.jatin.com/somepath` which means It needs path based routing which Is supported by `aws ALB`.

`I need performance as well as path based routing` **achievable with NLB?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> achievable with NLB?

Sadly **its not possible**. Concepts of url, paths or dns hostnames are only defined for [Layer 7 - Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) of the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). However, NLB operates at [layer 4 - transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer). Subsequently, NLB is not able to differentiate between any url domain names or paths.

The only distribution of incoming traffic you can obtained for NLB, is based on **port number**, as per my knowledge. So you can have one listener for port 80, other listener for port 88, 443 and so on. This will work because ports, just like IP addresses, are part of layer 4.

Only **ALB operates at layer 7** and partially CLB, thus it can do path based routing. So you either have to use ALB, or maybe try to look for a third party load balancer which you can deploy on AWS.

Comment: got your point, however i was going through this https://network.exampleloadbalancer.com/nlbsni_demo.html, how are they able to route on various hostname .com .info .net that too bahind a nlb using sni? isn't this routing based on hostname?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Thanks for link. I see this could work  for the domains only in https. But it it will not account for any paths.

Comment: thanks for the clarifiication, if you have time can you tell me how did they achieved that hsotbased routing using sni? you can update that in your answer so that it helps everyone in the future

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Sure, let me have a look.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I don't think now that's what they are doing. They have single listener that just responds to the different domains, but not distributes traffic to different TGs based on it. The only kind of distribution you could do, is based on ports. One listener is for port 80, other listener is for port 8080, 443 and so on. This does not require different domains nor ssl certs. And this works because port numbers are part of layer 4 - transport.

Comment: understood, thank you, if you want you can update that in your answer :)

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Yes, I already added ports to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: i just found out this https://network.exampleloadbalancer.com/nlbsni_detail.html here they don't want to use multiple listners, its confusing, also I think this architecture is not the very old one because in the architecture diagram the time timestamp if from 2019 year

Comment: @JatinMehrotra They write that different listeners for SNI are not practical due to port 443. You can't have multiple listeners for same port. So the SNI works on single listener for port 443. This way your ec2 instance can respond to different domains, but filtering based on domain is done on instances. Thus, your instance(s) can server websites for different domains if you setup apache or nginx to account for that.

Comment: You are correct @Marcin, even aws docs says the same `After you create a TLS listener, it has a default certificate and an empty certificate list. You can optionally add certificates to the certificate list for the listener. Using a certificate list enables the load balancer to support multiple domains on the same port and provide a different certificate for each domain. `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/create-tls-listener.html under certificate list section. thankyou!